# Puppetlabs Apache module: Debian PHP-FPM FastCGI APC

Tags: apache-2.2, puppet

I'm currently setting up a new web server on Debian Wheezy and use the following modules from the forge:

- http://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache
- http://forge.puppetlabs.com/example42/php

The PHP module is working fine and it installed the necessary files. I have two issues with the apache module

1. My config requires mod_event. The recommended way on Debian is usually to run

   ```
   a2enmod actions
   ```

I've tried to add `include apache::mod::actions` to my manifest, but that's just returns an error.

Although the puppet module has support for mod_actions, but this just seems to work on RHEL.

2. I need to a php-fpm.conf for apache, how would I do that with this module?
   http://www.queryadmin.com/506/apache2-php5-fpm-fastcgi-apc-debian-wheezy/

I hope you can give me a tip how to fix this problems. For now I just added it by hand, but I really want to have the config in puppet.

Thanks

Comment: "I've tried to add include apache::mod::actions to my manifest, but that's just returns an error." What is the error?

Comment: "Although the puppet module has support for mod_actions, but this just seems to work on RHEL." I think more than RHEL is supported; see https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/master/manifests/mod.pp